# How to pass SQLAlchemy session to the multiprocessing function?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing

I use SQLAlchemy to query the SQLite database and fetch some information for each element in a list. 
My worker function accepts an element and a session object to do its job.

But it's too slow when the list is long and the load of my CPU is rather low (10%).

So I think it is a good idea to use multi-processing to make full use of my CPU and speed up a bit.
I use the [p_tqdm](https://github.com/swansonk14/p_tqdm) package to do this, which is based on the `pathos.multiprocessing.ThreadPool` and `tqdm`.

My code is like `result = p_map(job, my_list, session)`, and I encountered a `PicklingError`:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session'>: it's not the same object as sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session
```

The same error occurred even if I use `multiprocessing.Pool`:

> ```
> with Pool(2) as p:
>     result = p.starmap(job, zip(my_list, repeat(session)))
> ```

Does it mean I cannot pass the session object when using multi-processing? All of my database operations is querying using `SELECT`, how can I make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you fire a query per item in the list? Have you considered the possibility of using a single query to fetch all related items? The usual answer to "How do I share a `Session` between processes?" is "You cannot", because the connection held by the session should not be shared in most cases. Each process should create their own connection pool, i.e. `Engine`, and their own sessions.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yes, you're right. I fire one query per item. I use the ORM to query objects and its related objects (e.g. person and his friends), is it possible to fetch all people's friends in a single command with ORM? Or I must use the raw SQL to do this?

Comment: SQLAlchemy offers a multitude of eager loading methods. It sounds like you've either one-to-many or many-to-many, for which the select-in style eager loading is a good choice. See for example https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#select-in-loading. So you could gather user IDs from your list, use an `IN` predicate to fetch all users and eager loading to fetch their related friends.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks! The select-in method is rather complicated to me, and I also tried to create an engine and session in each `job` function, but I got this error message: `NameError: name 'create_engine' is not defined`. I am confused.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I managed to use the eager loading methods, it reduced the time by about 20%, can I do multi-processing upon it?

Comment: But are you still fetching all the users one by one based on the list? I think this would be a good time to read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. It seems your real problem is "Fetching users based on a list is slow" and you've decided that the solution is multiprocessing and ask about that, when it might be better to ask about the original problem.